# Why does a pulley with a mass not have potential energy?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, potential-energy

As I was watching Youtube videos solving Pulley systems using a Lagrangian method, in particular Atwood Machines, I noticed that Pulleys with a mass have a KE of $\ (1/2) I \omega^2$  but have no potential energy. Why is this? Is it because they are fixed on a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the center of mass of the pulley does not move up or down. So, the pulley does have gravitational potential energy, it just isn't relevant.